How do I select a respondent's value if conditions are met by row?
I have a dataset that looks like this. For respondents who only picked one favorite fruit, I need to have variable returned that is a factor which is that respondent's favorite fruit. If a respondent picked more than one favorite fruit, their value should be NA.
fav_apple<-sample(c(NA,1), size=100, replace=T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
fav_orange<-sample(c(NA,1), size=100, replace=T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
fav_banana<-sample(c(NA,1), size=100, replace=T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
df<-data.frame(fav_apple, fav_orange, fav_banana)
df$id<-seq(1,nrow(df))

I tried tackling this with pivot_longer and then repivotting, but I end up with duplicate rows.

Using ifelse on the rowSums. Since favorites is a numeric matrix apply can be used efficiently on as.matrix(df[,1:3])
colnms <- colnames(df[,1:3])

cbind(df, 
  favorite = as.factor(unlist(
    ifelse(rowSums(df[,1:3], na.rm=T) == 1, 
           apply(as.matrix(df[,1:3]), 1, \(x) colnms[which(!is.na(x))]), 
           NA))))
    fav_apple fav_orange fav_banana  id   favorite
1          NA         NA         NA   1       <NA>
2          NA         NA         NA   2       <NA>
3          NA          1         NA   3 fav_orange
4          NA         NA         NA   4       <NA>
5           1          1          1   5       <NA>
6          NA         NA         NA   6       <NA>
7          NA         NA         NA   7       <NA>
8          NA         NA         NA   8       <NA>
9          NA         NA         NA   9       <NA>
10         NA         NA         NA  10       <NA>
11         NA         NA         NA  11       <NA>
12         NA         NA         NA  12       <NA>
13         NA         NA         NA  13       <NA>
14         NA         NA         NA  14       <NA>
15         NA         NA          1  15 fav_banana
...


Is there a spelling mistake in apply(as.matrix(df[,1:3]), 1, \(x) **colnms**[which(!is.na(x))]),             NA))))

See colnms <- colnames(df[,1:3])

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
fav_apple <- sample(c(NA, 1), size = 100, replace = T, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
fav_orange <- sample(c(NA, 1), size = 100, replace = T, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
fav_banana <- sample(c(NA, 1), size = 100, replace = T, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
df <- data.frame(fav_apple, fav_orange, fav_banana)
df$id <- seq(1, nrow(df))
# find rows with only one fruit selected
idx <- (rowSums(df |> select(-id), na.rm = TRUE) == 1) |> which()
# find the column for the single fruit the user selected
fruits <- df[ idx, -4 ] |> apply(1, \(x) which(x == 1)) |> unlist() |> as.numeric()
df$favorite_fruit <- NA
# select the column name of the single favorite fruit
df[ idx, ]$favorite_fruit <- colnames(df)[ fruits ]
# extract id and favorite fruit
df |> filter(!is.na(favorite_fruit)) |> mutate(favorite = str_remove(favorite_fruit, 'fav_')) |> print()


This is promising ...what does \(x) do?

"\(x)" is is shorthand for "function(x)"

OK, great. Can you explain what colnames(df)[ fruits ] is doing?

colnames function gets the column names for the data.frame object, the fruits vector contains the indices of columns for rows where the user selected a single favorite fruit

Somehow, when I run this code applied to my data-set, fruits is empty.

Please see edited code above

Ok, now I'm getting this error: ! Row indexes 7, 10, 13, 14, 8, and 14 more are used more than once for   assignment.

Using pivot_longer and left_join:
df |> 
  left_join(
    pivot_longer(df, cols=-id, names_prefix="fav_") |>
    filter(value==1) |>
    summarise(favourite=ifelse(n()>1, NA, name), .by=id), by="id")

    fav_apple fav_orange fav_banana  id favourite
1          NA         NA         NA   1      <NA>
2          NA         NA         NA   2      <NA>
3          NA         NA         NA   3      <NA>
4          NA         NA         NA   4      <NA>
5          NA         NA         NA   5      <NA>
6          NA         NA         NA   6      <NA>
7          NA         NA         NA   7      <NA>
8          NA         NA         NA   8      <NA>
9          NA         NA         NA   9      <NA>
10         NA         NA          1  10    banana
11         NA         NA         NA  11      <NA>
12         NA         NA         NA  12      <NA>
13         NA          1         NA  13    orange
14          1         NA         NA  14     apple
15         NA         NA         NA  15      <NA>
16         NA          1          1  16      <NA>
17         NA          1         NA  17    orange
18         NA         NA         NA  18      <NA>
19         NA         NA         NA  19      <NA>
20         NA         NA         NA  20      <NA>
# ℹ 80 more rows


library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

set.seed(1234)

fav_apple <- sample(c(NA,1), size=100, replace=T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
fav_orange <- sample(c(NA,1), size=100, replace=T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
fav_banana <- sample(c(NA,1), size=100, replace=T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
df <- data.frame(fav_apple, fav_orange, fav_banana)
df$id <- seq(1, nrow(df))

